# How to convert a String to a React Node/element

Tags: string, react-native, render, html-react-parser

I'm keeping a menu list in my database, and with it I also keep the icons. The challenge is that the Icons are MUI icons and being saved as the React node element.
For example:
`<HomeIcon fontSize="small" />`

When I'm rendering the menu list, everything looks great, BESIDE the icons - as it render them as text and not as React elements.

I tried so many options to render them as React, but couldn't find the right solution.

The last thing I used is Parse ('html-react-parser'), but with no success as it saves the elements in lower cases.

This is the parsing code:

```
  const icon = (item.icon ? parse(item.icon, {lowerCaseTags: false}) : "");
```

But then I'm receiving the following error:

```
Warning: The tag <homeicon> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
    at homeicon
    at span
```

That's the React node that I'm rendering:

```
     <DashboardSidebarItem
        active={partialMatch}
        chip={item.chip}
        depth={depth}
        icon={icon}
        info={item.info}
        key={key}
        open={partialMatch}
        path={item.path}
        title={item.title}
      >
        {renderNavItems({
          depth: depth + 1,
          items: item.children,
          path
        })}
      </DashboardSidebarItem>
```

And that's DashboardSidebarItem element:

```
export const DashboardSidebarItem = (props) => {
  const {
    active,
    children,
    chip,
    depth,
    icon,
    info,
    open: openProp,
    path,
    title,
    ...other
  } = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(openProp);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen);
  };

  let paddingLeft = 24;

  if (depth > 0) {
    paddingLeft = 32 + 8 * depth;
  }
// I NEED TO CONVERT IT TO REACT NATIVE
  // Branch
  if (children) {
    return (
      <ListItem
        disableGutters
        sx={{
          display: 'block',
          mb: 0.5,
          py: 0,
          px: 2
        }}
        {...other}>
        <Button
          endIcon={!open
            ? <ChevronRightIcon fontSize="small" />
            : <ChevronDownIcon fontSize="small" />}
          disableRipple
          onClick={handleToggle}
          startIcon={icon}
          sx={{
            color: active ? 'secondary.main' : 'neutral.300',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            pl: `${paddingLeft}px`,
            pr: 3,
            textAlign: 'left',
            textTransform: 'none',
            width: '100%',
            '&:hover': {
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255, 0.08)'
            },
            '& .MuiButton-startIcon': {
              color: active ? 'secondary.main' : 'neutral.400'
            },
            '& .MuiButton-endIcon': {
              color: 'neutral.400'
            }
          }}
        >
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            {title}
          </Box>
          {info}
        </Button>
        <Collapse
          in={open}
          sx={{ mt: 0.5 }}
        >
          {children}
        </Collapse>
      </ListItem>
    );
  }

  // Leaf
  return (
    <ListItem disableGutters sx={{display: 'flex', mb: 0.5, py: 0, px: 2 }}>
      <NextLink href={path} passHref >
        <Button
          component="a"
          startIcon={icon}
          endIcon={chip}
          disableRipple
          sx={{
            backgroundColor: active && 'rgba(255,255,255, 0.08)',
            borderRadius: 1,
            color: active ? 'secondary.main' : 'neutral.300',
            fontWeight: active && 'fontWeightBold',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            pl: `${paddingLeft}px`,
            pr: 3,
            textAlign: 'left',
            textTransform: 'none',
            width: '100%',
            '& .MuiButton-startIcon': {
              color: active ? 'secondary.main' : 'neutral.400'
            },
            '&:hover': {
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255, 0.08)'
            }
          }}
        >
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            {title}
          </Box>
          
          {info}
        </Button>
      </NextLink>
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend you to do any kind of parsing due security vulnerabilities like XSS.

I could be wrong but if you are loading icons from the database like:

```
<homeicon/>
```

Remember that user components must be capitalized, btw, you also need to import the icons before using them, so, a better approach would be:

- Instead of storing in the database the whole component, just store the icon name.
- Use the Icon component from the official documentation and just pass the icon name as a children.

Navigate to the following section for more details: Icon (Font icons)

- https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/

This is a basic example of the whole implementation:

```
import Icon from '@mui/material/Icon';

const IconList = ({ icons = [] }) => {
 return (
  <>
    {icons.map({name} => <Icon>{name}</Icon>)}
  </>
 );
};
```

In this way you could also store props like color, sx, fontSize, etc, from the official material-ui documentation and store them in the database to make the component more escalable.

Comment: @user1488098 If you need extra help or something please let me know!

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working.
<Icon>star</Icon> doesn't show a Star, but the word 'star'.

Comment: Did you load the CDN? <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
/>

Comment: Do you mean in package-lock.json?
I'm using React

Comment: No, if you look at the documentation you will see the following description: "Icon will by default set the correct base class name for the Material Icons font (filled variant). All you need to do is load the font, for instance, via Google Web Fonts:" So, you need to add the CDN to your index.html, it's usually placed at the public folder: "public/index.html", just add that link at the <head> section. @user1488098

Comment: Added it under index.html in 'public' folder, but still the same :-(

Comment: Do you have another idea of maybe to load the icon by it's name?

Comment: Please, take a look at the following sandbox that I created, It should work, you must be missing one dependency or maybe you added the link stylesheet in another place. Review my package.json, App.js and public/index.html: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-water-129oem?file=/src/App.js @user1488098